# Access is denied despite using broadFileSystemAccess

Tags: c#, uwp, manifest

UWP is killing me.....

I had to reinstall VisualStudio2017 after a computer crash. And now, my app that was working perfectly well before the crash refuses to work.

I've been using the broadFileSystemAccess capability in the Package Manifest, as per the instructions in the MS documentation:

```
 xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
 IgnorableNamespaces="rescap uap mp desktop4 iot2">
```

and

```
<Capabilities>
<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

This worked no problem, but now I get an underlined rescap:Capability and the compile warning "The element 'Capabilities' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' has invalid child element 'Capability' in namespace .......

Since it's a warning, it compiles without a hickup. However, the application cannot access files (access denied) justa s if this manifest code wasn't there.

I'm holding back saying bad words.... anybody has any idea of what is causing this? It's a fresh VS2017 install.

Thanks!

Comment: did you install all the updates to VS after installing?

Comment: First of all, open settings -> privacy -> file system acces (something like that), and check if you'r hasn't somehow been denied that access.

Comment: jdweng yes, i did.  Mailosz the other apps on this computer access the file system without problem. (Including uwp apps)

Comment: Ok. Deployed the application, right clicked on its logo, chose more and then "App Settings". In there there is a on/offfor File System. Switched this to "on" as it was "Off" by default and Bob's my uncle..... Could it be the fall 2018 update? How to turn this on programatically by default?

Comment: @FrancoisGagnon I've the exact same issue. Have you resolved yours yet. If yes, could you please share your resolution. Thank you.?

Comment: @nam the way I resolved it temporarily is to right click on the application, choose More then AppSettings and in the AppsPermissions enable "FileSystem". Really cumbersome and frustrating. I'm really starting to give up on UWP, as many others are around. I can't understand why Microsoft insists on making simple things complicated or impossible. Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

Ok so heres some of my findings.

**1.  an app must not declare both broadFileSystemAccess and any of the other three file-system capabilities. (Pictures, documents, downloads)**

source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/415d02da-eeb6-45b3-b6e2-946b124d14b0/broadfilesystemaccess-issue?forum=wpdevelop

**2. This only works with the `storageFile` api NOT `File.Exists etc` api**

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

**3. Make sure the fileAccess is enabled as with the other two answers:**

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57703368/2987066

**4. I also found that every time I started debugging (and the code had changed) I needed to turn that setting on and off again to get it to work**

source: frustratingly debugging the application through trial and error

Thanks microsoft for your excellent development environment, it really shows how much developers love developing your apps as your store is really flourishing in comparison to your competitors... oh wait..

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for reporting this issue. It's a known issue in 1809. The relevant team is working on it.

Clint Rutkas has replied on this thread: [No user-consent prompt on first run of broadFileSystemAccess-capable UWP app](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/35781934-no-user-consent-prompt-on-first-run-of-broadfilesy).

He suggested that we could use `try/catch` to catch this scenario:

```
try
{
    StorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"E:\Foo");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // prompt user for what action they should do then launch below
    // suggestion could be a message prompt
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:appsfeatures-app"));
}
```

Comment: UWP forces developers to be disciplined and explicit in the way we use the file system, but when we do it according to the rules and to the published documentation to the t, or does not work. What's wrong with that picture?

Comment: There is a reason why it was called a Disk Operating System back in the old days... it's kinda central to operating the machine....

Comment: 1 year on and still no fix. Thanks Microsoft

Answer (score 2):

You also need to allow your app access to the file system in Settings.  This a safety measure so the user of the machine acknowledges your app can have access outside the controlled access to files provided by the UWP app container it runs in.

[image]

Comment: Hummm.... let's see this....Thanks.  I still fail to see why Microsoft is locking everything up that way in UWP while WPF allow you to access files without a problem. If they do this for security and I was a hacker, I'd develop in WPF instead.... what's the point! They make everything unnecessarily complicated with UWP. The end-result, for example, in their VR environment where they enforce UWP: people develop using Steam instead of their own Mixed Reality environment.

Comment: UWP runs inside a container; a strictly controlled sandbox.  WPF does not.  Containers are much friendlier to the OS as they provide more protection to the user  from rogue apps and enable advanced installation management scenarios (see MSIX).  Unfortunately it places a little more demand on the developer.

Comment: As for the hacker use case, yes you would use WPF over UWP. In the far future however, even your WPF will be packaged in an MSIX installation, which forces you into an MSIX app container.  You will have the same issues with broad file access.