# Unity Build targets Mixed Reality but does not appear in apps

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, windows-mixed-reality

I have created a project using the Windows XR Plugin and XR Plugin management. I am NOT using the XR interaction toolkit, I have created my own tools, including my own XRRig using the Tracked Pose Driver.

My project is NOT built with UWP since I need file access that UWP does not provide or is too tricky to provide (after many attempts and work with a senior developer here, I just gave up). So I'm using standard Unity and my build settings are "PC, MAC, Linux stand-alone". My Player settings in the XR Plug-in management are "Windows Mixed Reality". I am using a few UWP functions for file access within the app.

Now, once the build is built, I obviously don't see it within Steam, but it also does not appear in the Mixed Reality list of applications. I have to start it manually by clicking on the icon on the desktop. It works great, but wtf...?

I know for applications to appear in Mixed Reality they must be built with UWP, but then if this build is neither UWP nor Steam, what is it then? How do I add it (or sideload it) to the Mixed Reality applications that the Windows menu brings up within the cliff house for e.g.?

Comment: Whenever UWP build is always our recommendation. Could you explain the file access issue you got? Have you tried the solution post as a comment in this thread: [How to save files to Documents folder on Hololens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58234292/how-to-save-files-to-documents-folder-on-hololens?noredirect=1#comment102997171_58234292)？

Comment: I'm building a video library viewer and the "broadfilesystem" requirements does not work. UWP is just too finicky, posted many questions here related to it. Look here, amongst other things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53518621/access-is-denied-despite-using-broadfilesystemaccess

Comment: But that still does not answer my question. I don't mind reading and searching, but where?

Answer (score 0):

To answer first question on what type of application is being built if UWP and Steam are removed as target in Unity, this is being built as a PC desktop application.

To answer the second question on how to access this application inside the Mixed Reality Cliff House shell when the application is not a UWP application, this can be launched via the “Classic Apps” pin inside the mixed reality cliff house shell.

Here is more information on the "Classic Apps" pin:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/whats-new/release-notes-may-2019#how-to-launch

That should answer the question asked on how to launch inside of VR experience itself.